# How to merge java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc, time, date

I have two objects: a `java.sql.Date` and a `java.sql.Time`.
What is the best way to merge them into single `java.util.Date`?

In the database those columns are stored separately. I get them by JDBC `rs.getDate("Date")` and `rs.getTime("Time");`.

Comment: Why don't you use java.sql.Timestamp to set date and time at once?

Comment: In database those columns stored separately. I get them by JDBC rs.getDate("Date") and rs.getTime("Time");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create two Calendar instances. In the first you initialize the date and in the latter the time. You can the extract the time values from the "time" instance and set them to the "date".

```
  // Construct date and time objects
  Calendar dateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
  dateCal.setTime(date);
  Calendar timeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
  timeCal.setTime(time);

  // Extract the time of the "time" object to the "date"
  dateCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
  dateCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
  dateCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, timeCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));

  // Get the time value!
  date = dateCal.getTime();
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See modern approach in Answer by Ole V.V.

Answer (score 4):

[The answer by istovatis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19383785/5772882) is correct except for not carrying the milliseconds over. I should like to contribute the modern answer. `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time` are now long outdated, and their replacements, the `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` classes, make your task much simpler. Assuming you are using Java 8 or later and [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 or higher, get those types from your result set and combine them:

```
    LocalDate date = rs.getObject("Date", LocalDate.class);
    LocalTime time = rs.getObject("Time", LocalTime.class);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(time);
```

In case you don’t have direct access to your SQL result set and get `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time` from some legacy API that you cannot change, I recommend you convert to the modern types and then use the same way of merging:

```
    LocalDate date = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
    LocalTime time = sqlTime.toLocalTime();

    LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(time);
```

You asked for a `java.util.Date`. That class too is long outdated, so it’s better to use the `LocalDateTime` from the above code (or perhaps convert to `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`, depending on what you will be using it for). If you do need a `Date` for some other legacy API that you cannot change either, convert like this:

```
    Instant inst = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from(inst);
```

If your legacy API required a `Timestamp` object, it is even simpler:

```
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime);
```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

Both have time and day, so you could do something like:

```
Date d = new Date(2013, 11, 23);
Time t = new Time(23, 45, 45);
d.setMinutes(t.getMinutes());
d.setHours(t.getHours());
d.setSeconds(t.getSeconds());
```

Comment: Bear in mind that those methods are deprecated because of very poor implementation of the concept of both Dates and Times.

Comment: Yes, I know, but if (s)he wants to do precisely that, I guess (s)he already knows it.

Comment: Using of deprecated methods is not a best way to do that.